# How to access Log4Net after adding it to Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, log4net, .net-5

This is my first time working with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore`.

I have a WPF application where I add the Log4Net provider within the `CreateDefaultBuilder` in `App` method of `App.xaml.cs`. Immediately after, I want to write to the log file using `LogInformation` saying "Starting Application". From what I can tell, it does not seem like I can do this because of the way it has been added to the Dependency Injection container. I must either call a method that accesses the DI container in the parameter list or add `Log4Net` to the `ServiceProvider` and then retrieve the service that way. But, that does not seem right because I will effectively have Log4Net added to DI twice.

Is there a way to immediately access the DI container after configuring Log4Net so I can write to the log file?

```
Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, appBuilder) =>
{
   // Do some stuff here    
}).ConfigureLogging(logBuilder =>
{
   logBuilder.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Trace);
   logBuilder.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
})
.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
{      
   Configuration = context.Configuration;

   ConfigureServices(Configuration, services);
})
.Build();

ServiceProvider = Host.Services;

// How to access Log4Net here?
_ISomeLogger.LogInformation("Starting Application");
```

**Update**

I am using the following example: https://www.thecodebuzz.com/logging-using-log4net-net-core-console-application/

Comment: I don't get WPF and ASP.Net together? In an Asp.Net Core Application you would now inject ILogger into your class (a service, a controller something like that) and use that.

Comment: @Ralf See updated question. I am using an example that I found on the website. I too agree that is seems counterintuitive to use a class from what appears to be a different framework. But, I have done this previously when adding the `AddAzureKeyVault` to a WPF application for hosting in an Azure Virtual Machine.

Comment: Your container is configured with the call to build(). So retrieving the logger from the ServiceProvider you have is the earliest time were you can log.

Comment: `logger = ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger>();   logger.LogInformation("Starting Application");`

Comment: That comes back Null. But, you are close. It needs to be `logger = (ILogger<Program>)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<Program>));`
I could have swore I tried this earlier, but it did not work. I think I was missing the Type casting. Anyways, this works. If you post it as the answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to access the `Log4Net` from the `ServiceProvider` right after building it:

```
logger = (ILogger<Program>)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(ILogger<Program>));
```

Comment: Is that first cast really required?

Comment: No, I just do it by convention.